# Properties of observable are undefined

Tags: angular, observable, ngxs

I have an observable in my `AppComponent`:

```
@Select(MyState.config) config$: Observable<Config>;
```

This is populated with an `Action`:

```
@Action(GetConfig)
getConfig(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>) {
    return this.configService.getConfig().pipe(tap(
        data => {
            ctx.setState(patch({ data: patch({ config: data }) }));
        }
    ));
}
```

A variable is then defined to hold the value of the observable:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  config: Config;
```

Which is then populated via a function (called by `ngOnInit()`):

```
  populateConfig = () => {
    this.config$.pipe(filter(a => a != null), distinctUntilChanged(), takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(data => {
      this.config = data;
    });
  }
```

And then the `config` variable is used in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="config">
    {{config.details.username}}
</div>
```

The problem is that the template then throws an error in the console:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
```

If I `console.log(JSON.stringify())` the `data` values I can clearly see the `details.username` properties within but I cannot make use of these same values once `data` is assigned to `this.config`. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn’t have an additional prop in there so it ends being something like config.config.details maybe? Just do a {{ config | json }} in your template to see exactly what is in there..

Comment: It seems that you're accessing the `details` because it's initialized. Try to change the filter used in the `pouplateConfig` method to be like the following: `filter(a => !!a?.details)`.

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, I'm sure. The `{{config|json}}` output dumps exactly the same as using `console.log(JSON.stringify())`. The problem is that while I can see the value as a property of the `this.config` object, if I try to reference `this.config.details.username` I get the error, telling me that `this.config.details` is undefined. Why would that be? Especially considering that I can dump it out to the console just fine.

Comment: @Amer Not sure what you're getting at with that expression.

Comment: I didn't test it. I suggested editing your code to handle the nullable `details` within the `filter` operator.